# how to merge to a branch that is ahead?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

We have 3 branches in the project. Firstly we make development in "development" branch, we merge to "test". We test via jenkins. After we merge to "demo". Customer uses this branch with jenkins again.

But an unknown error occured during the first merge. Test branch doesn't work as well. We tried reset to this commit thing but source tree doesn't allow to push without pull. We have to create new branch but this situation can mess up with jenkins connection. Now I resetted to working commit and created new branch. So I want to merge to test branch but test branch is ahead already. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Rebase` your branch with test branch or `merge`  test branch into your branch.

Comment: @PankajGadge Why rebase?

Comment: just remove `test` branch and create a new `test` branch based on `demo`

Comment: Please post a picture of the branches. Can you post a pictoral representation of your branches? Or at the least use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` and paste the results because it's hard to see the current state of your rep from what you've described?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that you want to go backwards in your test branch.

1. First get on your test branch: `git checkout test`
2. Now determine the commit you want to go to:  `git log --oneline -10`. This will give you a list of the 10 most recent commits on the test branch.
3. Make a note of the SHA of the commit you want to get to.
4. Now you have to decide what you want to do: (i) you can reset the test branch to this SHA - or if you are feeling nervous or not confident about that, you can preserve everything as it exists but can (ii) create a new test branch (call it test-1) and go back to the situation where the code was working. `git checkout -b test-1 SHAofTheCommitYouWantToGoBackTo`.
5. Work on the test-1 branch. When you are happy with that you can perhaps delete the old test branch.
6. When you are happy with everything you can merge it into the demo branch. If the demo branch isn't working, then you'll have to go backwards: either by resetting, or by creating another demo branch (call it demo-1) - just follow the above instructions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to **force push `test` branch to remote** by `git push origin test -f` (unnecessary to create new branch).

Assume the commit history on `development` and `test` branches as below:

```
…---A---B---C  test, origin/test
           /
…-----D---E    development, origin/development
```

So the merge commit merged from `development` into `test` branch is commit `C` in above graph.

After you reset the merged commit `C` on `test` branch (`git reset --hard HEAD~` on test branch), the commit history will be:

```
       test
        |
…---A---B---C origin/test
           /
…-----D---E   development, origin/development
```

Since the commit `C` is the merge commit, the commits existing in `origin/test` also contains the commits on `development` branch (second parent for merge). You can double check by `git log test..origin/test --oneline` (the command list the commits existing on `origin/test` branch and not existing on `test` branch), it will list the commits `C`,  `E` and `D` etc.

You can execute `git push origin test -f` on `test` branch, then the commit history will be:

```
 …---A---B  test,origin/test

…-----D---E   development, origin/development
```

Then you can continue works on `development` and `test` branches. When it's ready to merge `development` branch into `test` branch, you can merge again, and then build the test branch in Jenkins.

Besides, if you also want to reset the merge commit on `demo` branch, you should also force push local `demo` branch to remote.